# Replacing spaces in lists

Tags: python-3.x

I'm creating a google searcher in python. Is there any way that I can replace a space in a list with a "+" for my url? This is my code so far:

```
q=input("Question=")
qlist=list(q)
#print(qlist)
```

Can I replace any spaces in my list with a plus, and then turn that back into a string?

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add another line of thought there.  Try the [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/urllib2.html) library for parsing url strings.

Here's an example:

```
import urllib

## Create an empty dictionary to hold values (for questions and answers).
data = dict()

## Sample input
input = 'This is my question'

### Data key can be 'Question'
data['Question='] = input

### We'll pass that dictionary hrough the urlencode method
url_values = urllib.parse.urlencode(data)

### And print results
print(url_values)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Alternatively, you can setup the dictionary a little better if you only have a couple of key-value pairs

## Input
input = 'This is my question'

# Our dictionary; We can set the input value as the value to the Question key
data = {
    'Question=': input
    }

print(urllib.parse.urlencode(data))
```

Output:

```
'Question%3D=This+is+my+question'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just join it together to create 1 long string.

```
qlist = my_string.split(" ")
result = "+".join(qlist)
print("Output string: {}".format(result))
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the join and split operations in python.

```
q = 'dog cat'
list_info = q.split()
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
q = ['dog', 'cat']
s_info = ''.join(q)
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join